# Segmentation fault (core dumped) run time bug with MaxPairwiseProduct program

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, memory, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int MaxPairwiseProduct(vector<int>& numbers);
    //declaration
    vector<int> *x;
    x->push_back(1);
    x->push_back(2);

    int answer = MaxPairwiseProduct(*x);
    cout << answer;
}

int MaxPairwiseProduct(vector<int>& numbers) {
    int index1 =  1;
    int index2;

    //vector<int> numbers = number;
    int n = numbers.size();
    for(int i = 2;i < n;++i){
        if(numbers[i]>numbers[index1]){
            index1 = i;
            }
    }
    if(index1 == 1){
        index2 = 2;
    } else {
    index2 = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 1;i < n;++i){
        if(numbers[i] != numbers[index1] && numbers[i]>numbers[index2]){
            index2 = i;
        }
    }
    numbers[index1] * numbers[index2];
    return numbers[index1] * numbers[index2];
}
```

I am trying to implement a seemingly advance algorithm to find the max pair wise product. I continue to get Segmentation fault (core dumped) errors and I know it has something to do with my pointers and scope of my functions perhaps. Any advice or tips?

Comment: `vector<int> *x;` your vector pointer is never initialized to a valid instance. Why are you using a pointer there at all?

Comment: B.c. I can I guess lol, want to make sure I remember memory management in C++. How do I go about initializing it to a valid instance?

Comment: The best way would be not to use a pointer at all: `vector<int> x;` and replace the dereferencing `->` arrows with `.`, also omit the `*` when you pass it to the other function.

Comment: I did that also and am now getting 0 as an answer which is false.

Comment: That's probably another issue. I'd recommend you run your code in the debugger and step through line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int MaxPairwiseProduct(vector<int>& numbers);
    //declaration
    vector<int> *x = new vector<int>();
    x->push_back(7);
    x->push_back(4);
    x->push_back(5);
    x->push_back(6);


    int answer = MaxPairwiseProduct(*x);

    cout << answer;delete x;
}

int MaxPairwiseProduct(vector<int>& numbers) {
    int index1 =  1;
    int index2;

    //vector<int> numbers = number;
    int n = numbers.size();
    for(int i = 0;i < n;++i){
        if(numbers[i]>numbers[index1]){
            index1 = i;
            }
    }
    if(index1 == 1){
        index2 = 2;
    } else {
    index2 = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < n;++i){
        if(numbers[i] != numbers[index1] && numbers[i]>numbers[index2]){
            index2 = i;
        }
    }

    return numbers[index1] * numbers[index2];
}
```

I got it to work there was an odd late night brain fart.

Comment: Hey - welcome to stackoverflow! Your code looks good. I just wanted to add that you don't have to create `x` as a pointer to a vector. Using it just as a vector would work fine, and then you wouldn't have to call the `delete` at the end

It'd look like `vector<int> x = vector<int>();` or, alternatively, `vector<int> x{}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    long MaxPairwiseProductFast(vector<long>& numbers);

    long N, input;
    vector<long> *V = new vector<long>();
    cin >> N;


    do {
                V->push_back(input);}
    while (V->size() <= N && cin >> input);

    long answer = MaxPairwiseProductFast(*V);

    cout << answer;
    delete V;
}

 long MaxPairwiseProductFast(vector<long>& numbers) {
    int index1 =  1;
    int index2 = 1;

    int n = numbers.size();
    for(int i = 2;i < n;++i){
        if(numbers[i]>numbers[index1]){
            index1 = i;
            }
    }
    if(index1 == 1){
        index2 = 2;
    } else {
    index2 = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 2;i < n;++i){
        if(i != index1 && numbers[i]>numbers[index2]){
            index2 = i;
        }
    }

    return  (long)(numbers[index1] * numbers[index2]);
}

long MaxPairwiseProduct(vector<long>& A) {
int index = 1;
int n = A.size();
for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i){
    if (A[i] > A[index]){
        index = i;
    }
}
swap(A[index], A[n]);
index = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < n-1; ++i){
    if(A[i] > A[index]){
        index = i;
    }
}
swap(A[index], A[n - 1]);
return A[n-1] * A[n];
}
```

Modified version with user defined size of vector and the ability to define user input values.